# Is it possible to use more than one custom font in an SVG?

Tags: svg, fonts, itext, itext7

I'm using the *Univers LT 47 Condensed Light* font in SVG. In some of the elements use the *Univers LT 47 Condensed Bold* font. The SVG is rendered correctly but when I print the SVG on a PDF none of the fonts are respected and a default font (Times) is used.

Later on, i figured out that with setting a (the?) font provider I'm able to use the standard font.

```
string fontUniverseLT47 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("fonts/lte50144.ttf"),
fontUniverseLT47Bold = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("fonts/LT.ttf");

FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();
provider.AddFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(fontUniverseLT47));
provider.AddFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(fontUniverseLT47Bold));

SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
props.SetCharset("Windows-1252");
props.SetFontProvider(provider);

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(svg);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    Image image = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(ms, pdf, props);
    image.SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
    image.SetFixedPosition(llx, lly);
    image.ScaleToFit(width, height);

    doc.Add(image);
}
```

But now I'd like to use the bold font which cannot be set in CSS with font-weight : bold as it's a different PdfFont.

Is there a way how I can use the second, bold font in the SVG?

Comment: Why couldn't you add your second font to the `FontProvider`'s instance you use?

Comment: I tried this but when I adding more fonts to the same provider does only respect the first one and when I add more than one provider to the properties only the last one is being respected.